# How do I pass data from a view to a custom mixin in Django?

Tags: django

Two of my views share a substantial amount of code, which makes it hard to maintain. For that reason I decided to move the common code into a custom mixin.

A simplistic example:

```
class StatisticsMixin(object):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        user_products = Product.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).select_related()

        context["total_products"] = user_products.count()
        context["total_products_open"] = user_products.total_new()

        return context
```

Now, my views would look like this:

```
class DashboardView(LoginRequiredMixin, StatisticsMixin, TemplateView):
    model = Product
    template_name = "products/dashboard.html"

     def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        user_products = Product.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).select_related()

        # Some other code

        return context

class AnalyticsView(LoginRequiredMixin, StatisticsMixin, TemplateView):
    model = Product
    template_name = "products/analytics.html"

     def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        user_products = Product.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).select_related()

        # Some other code

        return context
```

The issue is the following in the custom mixin, StatisticsMixin:

```
user_products = Product.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).select_related()
```

which in different views could be something else.

So, I am trying to find a way for the custom mixin, to get the data from the view and not be hardcoded in it.

Answer (score 3):

```
class StatisticsMixin(object):
    def get_user_products(self):
        return Product.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).select_related()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        user_products = self.get_user_products()

        context["total_products"] = user_products.count()
        context["total_products_open"] = user_products.total_new()

        return context

class DashboardView(LoginRequiredMixin, StatisticsMixin, TemplateView):
    model = Product
    template_name = "products/dashboard.html"

     def get_user_products(self):
        return what ever you want
```

Comment: In your answer, if ```DashboardView's get_user_products``` is different from ```StatisticsMixin's get_user_products``` what will happen ?

Comment: Use `DashboardView's get_user_products` instead of `StatisticsMixin's get_user_products`

Comment: You mean to use ```DashboardView's get_user_products``` in the ```get_context_data ``` of ```StatisticsMixin``` ?

Comment: Would you mind updating your answer with a more comprehensive example, so we can avoid extensive conversation in the comments ?